# Chebychev's inequality over a discrete random variable: $<$ vs $\le$

Tags: probability

By [Chebychev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) it holds that
$$
\begin{split}
Pr(|X-\mu |<\epsilon )>1-{\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{\epsilon ^{2}}} \\
\end{split}
$$

For a discrete random variable $X$, does the following hold?
$$
\begin{split}
Pr(|X-\mu | \le \epsilon )>1-{\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{\epsilon ^{2}}} \\
\end{split}
$$

Best regards

Comment: -1. Are you trolling? This is not Chebyhev's inequality

Comment: @kludg, "trolling"? LOL, not intentionally. Maybe I missed something. I referred to the last inequality in the section ["Proof assuming random variable X is continuous"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Proof_assuming_random_variable_X_is_continuous). I'll be happy if you'll elaborate what is wrong with what I wrote. Best regards

Comment: Ah, I see now, sorry. Wikipedia is trolling, or more likely is writing nonsense as it usually does. The Chebyshev's inequality is $$P(|X-\mu|\geq\epsilon)\leq 1- \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$$ and not what Wikipedia assumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the Chebyshev's inequality is
$$P(|X- \mu|\geq\epsilon)\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$$

In words, it says that if the variance
is small, then the random variable is unlikely to fall
too far off from the mean.